# Read first rows only from a .xml file

Tags: r, xml

I'm working with a big .xml file and i want to split it to test things before wasting a lot of time processing it.

How do i do it with {xml2}?

With .csv it'd be easy as `read.csv("data.csv", nrows=100)`

Comment: xml documents are not necessarily line-based, it's better to think of them as "lists", where the first three elements might be on line 1 or spanning lines 1-1000.

Comment: @r2evans nice! Can we get first lists?

Comment: An xml document is a structured document, yes, but they are all different. `xml2::read_xml` should return a named list from the document, so perhaps `xml2::read_xml("data.xml")[1:3]`?